# How do you animate a dynamically created Bootstrap button in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried to append and set position to absolute, but the dynamically created button does not animate at all.

```
$( "#btn" ).click(function() {
var $newguy = $('<li><button type="button" class="class-btn" id="class-name-num" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#class-modal">class_name</button></li>');
$("#class-listing").append($newguy);
$("#class-name-num").animate({'marginTop:':"-=375px"},500);
});
```

here is the css:

```
.class-btn{
background-color: #bcd97d;
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 50px;
display: inline-block;
border: 0px solid #000;
font-weight: bold;
width: 500px;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
z-index: 10;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Provide a demo that replicates problem. We have no way to know what CSS is being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact there're a lot of issues with your code.

You are code is wrong inside animate function, it should be like this:

```
$("#class-name-num").animate({'marginTop':-375},500);
```

Also button need to be a block.

```
$("#class-name-num").css({'display':"block"});
```

Also try to use classes not ids while you may add another items...

working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/zhgn5vd4/

Comment: thank you for your help. I know it's a little bad, it's my first time coding a web-page!